# Kali Linux: Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kali-linux, libraries, shared-library

I’m getting an error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libtbb.so.2: cannot open shared
> object file: No such file or directory

On Kali Linux.

Is there any way to fix this?

Yes, I tried to install the library but it throws me an error, installed the -dev library and the error persists.

Any help on this please? I’m desperate at this point.

```
sudo bin/bt_fuzzer
bin/bt_fuzzer: error while loading shared libraries: libtbb.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or di
rectory

sudo ldconfig -p | grep tbb 
       libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2 
       libtbbmalloc_proxy.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so 
       libtbbmalloc.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbbmalloc.so.2 
       libtbbmalloc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbbmalloc.so 
       libtbbbind_2_5.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbbbind_2_5.so.3 
       libtbbbind_2_5.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbbbind_2_5.so 
       libtbb.so.12 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.12 
       libtbb.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so 
       libbtbb.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbtbb.so.1
```

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] your question to show the complete output when you try to install the library (`sudo apt install libtbb2`).

Comment: please include the command that outputs the message

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @don_aman Done buddy.

Comment: The version of `bt_fuzzer` you are running was built against an older version of `libtbb.so` than is available on your distro.  The answer is to rebuild `bt_fuzzer` from source, linking against the dependencies available in your distro.

Comment: Or install whatever version of `bt_fuzzer` the actual Kali devs make available for their distro.

Answer (score -1):

Solved.

Managed to install libtbb2 on Kali Linux.

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tbb/libtbb2_2020.3-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libtbb2_2020.3-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: This method prevented any authentication of the installed package (interception could have happened. Considering Kali is about security, that's bad). And also: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian

Comment: Considering also Kali developers' explicit warning about mixing Kali with non-Kali sources as the most common reason of breaking Kali, I think @Stewart's recommendation of building from source against Kali's current libraries (`libtbb12` in this case) would be a safer option. This not as much for you, as for the future generations searching for help for the same issue :-)

Comment: Downvoting because while this *technically* works, absolutely everyone who knows how distributions in general or Kali and Debian in specific work will tell you that this is a *terribly bad idea and you shouldn't do it unless you know what you're doing*.